# How to set up hibernate in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, hibernate

I'm trying to set up hibernate in Ubuntu 18.4, however it's not working.

**First of all I'm checking the swap** according to the [guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23074) :

```
root@athos-ThinkPad-T460p:~# cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

it seems the swap is on.

**Then I tried `kernel (aka suspend or swsusp)`**, option 1 of [official ubuntu document on PowerManagement/Hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate). The guide says

> The way you manually trigger hibernation using this 'kernel' method is
>   to write 'disk' to /sys/power/state. There are two modes of 'kernel'
>   hibernation: platform and shutdown. If one does not work, you can try
>   the other:
>
> ```
> sudo -s
> echo platform > /sys/power/disk
> echo disk > /sys/power/state
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> sudo -s
> echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
> echo disk > /sys/power/state
> ```

But I got `write error: No such device` error on both case:

```
root@athos-ThinkPad-T460p:~# echo platform > /sys/power/disk
root@athos-ThinkPad-T460p:~# echo disk > /sys/power/state    
bash: echo: write error: No such device
root@athos-ThinkPad-T460p:~# 
root@athos-ThinkPad-T460p:~# echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
root@athos-ThinkPad-T460p:~# echo disk > /sys/power/state
bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

**Then I would like to try `toxonice`**, option 3 of [official ubuntu document on PowerManagement/Hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate). But there is no step-by-step guide, only some links such as  [tuxonice-userui](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tuxonice-userui) or [PPA Available](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), leading only to lots of documents and codes.

Pls kindly suggest how can I set up hibernate in ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Duplicate on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/): https://askubuntu.com/q/1031633/354350